# Como puedo acceder a una variable en un archivo config.ini

Tags: php, variables-globales, configuración

Como puedo obtener el valor de una variable que se encuentra en el archivo `config.ini` en la raíz de mi disco duro y poder utilizarlo para una consulta SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar **[`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-ini-file.php)**.

Si le pasas el parámtero `TRUE` al final te creará un array asociativo por secciones, si no le pasas nada te creará un array único.

Supongamos este archivo (puesto como ejemplo en el manual), el cual se llama `ejemplo.ini`:

```
; Este es un ejemplo de fichero de configuración
; Los comentarios empiezan con ';', como en php.ini

[primera_sección]
uno = 1
cinco = 5
animal = PÁJARO

[segunda_sección]
ruta = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"

[tercera_sección]
phpversion[] = "5.0"
phpversion[] = "5.1"
phpversion[] = "5.2"
phpversion[] = "5.3"

urls[svn] = "http://svn.php.net"
urls[git] = "http://git.php.net"
```

Para leerlo, el código sería:

```
$archivo="ejemplo.ini";  //aquí se debe poner la ruta correcta del archivo si fuera necesario

$array_ini = parse_ini_file($archivo);
print_r($array_ini);
```

`$array_ini`  sería un array como este:

```
Array
(
    [uno] => 1
    [cinco] => 5
    [animal] => Pájaro dodo
    [ruta] => /usr/local/bin
    [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
    [phpversion] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.0
            [1] => 5.1
            [2] => 5.2
            [3] => 5.3
        )

    [urls] => Array
        (
            [svn] => http://svn.php.net
            [git] => http://git.php.net
        )

)
```

Para leerlo, sería como leer cualquier array. Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el `1` y el `5`, harías:

```
$uno=$array_ini["uno"];
$cinco=$array_ini["cinco"];
```

---

Ahora lo leemos con `TRUE`:

```
$array_ini = parse_ini_file($archivo, TRUE);
print_r($array_ini);
```

El resultado sería un array asociativo en este caso:

```
Array
(
    [primera_sección] => Array
        (
            [uno] => 1
            [cinco] => 5
            [animal] => Pájaro dodo
        )

    [segunda_sección] => Array
        (
            [ruta] => /usr/local/bin
            [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
        )

    [tercera_sección] => Array
        (
            [phpversion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.0
                    [1] => 5.1
                    [2] => 5.2
                    [3] => 5.3
                )

            [urls] => Array
                (
                    [svn] => http://svn.php.net
                    [git] => http://git.php.net
                )

        )

)
```

Y para obtener resultados tendrías que acceder por secciones. Por ejemplo:

```
$seccUno=$array_ini["primera_sección"]
$uno=$seccUno["uno"];
$cinco=$seccUno["cinco"];
```